# How to iterate a range of numbers in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I wrote a simple `python` function for my friend to tell why a number is now a prime:

```
def why_not_prime(n):
    if n==2:
        print(n, "is a prime.")
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i == 0:
            print(n, "is not a prime because it could be divided by", i,".")
            break
        else:
            print(n, "is a prime.")
            break
```

I try to convert it to `Clojure`, but I couldn't find the way. I've no idea how to handle the `for i in range(2,n)`. What's the usual way to do it?

Comment: I don't think you spend much time on checking even introductory articles to Clojure. Searching for 'clojure' and 'looping' finds the relevant article right away: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/loop

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this claims `9` is a prime number. Basically, any non-prime that's not divisible by `2` is called prime by this.

Comment: @schaueho Thank you for pointing me the doc link. I need to read more doc.

Comment: @resueman Yes, you're right. There's something wrong with the logic. Actually, there's no else part in my first attempt. I run it with some proposed composite numbers. When I ask the question, I added the else part for completeness. I didn't notice that it was wrong. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Clojure, there's really no universal answer to this as it's decided by *why you want to iterate through those numbers*.
You might want to produce some value for each of the numbers and then collect them in a list, in which case you want to use `map` or `for`. You might want to "summarize" them in some way (like adding them all together) in which case you'd want to use something like `reduce`.
In this case you want a special kind of summary; you want to know if there is *some value* in the range which is "appropriate" (in this case a divisor of `n`). There is a core function for this kind of use case called `some`, but it needs a function to tell it what is an "appropriate" value. There's no base function which does all we want, but we can just create one.

```
(defn why-not-prime [n]
  (let[checker (fn [divisor] ;; A local function under the name checker, with one argument
                 (if (= 0 (mod n divisor));; If that argument is a divisor of n
                   divisor ;;then return it
                   false)) ;; otherwise return false - this value wasn't "appropriate"
       witness (some checker (range 2 n))] ;; witness will be the first value that satisfies checker
              ;if there isn't such a value, witness is nil
    (if witness
      (str n " is composite because it can be divided by " witness)
      (str n " is prime."))))
```

Now, this redefines your problem slightly, in that it doesn't *print* any message, but only *return* a string containing one. This is a more idiomatic formulation in a functional language where you usually defer side effects like printing as long as you can. If you want it to print, you can just wrap the entire function body with a `println`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution `checker -> witness` is very clear, and the explanation is quite helpful to the newbie. After reading your solution, I decide to: 1. Check the doc for the function `some`. 2. Read a Clojure book.